# C# how create a more complex .Any() expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression, any

i have this filter array that has property Name, value and propertyType.
Based on the PropertyType i build an Expression and finaly what i have is a list of expressions that i then aggregate with And.

```
return filter?
.Where(f => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Value))?
.Select(f =>
{
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
  var property = Expression.Property(parameter, PascalCase(f.PropertyName));

  Expression expression = null;

  if (f.Type == PropertyTypeEnum.String)
  {
      var toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", new Type[] { });
      var startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
      var value = Expression.Constant(f.Value.ToLower());
      var loweredProperty = Expression.Call(property, toLowerMethod);

      expression = Expression.Call(loweredProperty, startsWithMethod, value);
   }
   else
   {
     var value = Convert.ChangeType(f.Value, property.Type);

     ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(value);
     expression = Expression.Equal(property, constantExpression);
   }

   return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
 });
```

which i place in a Linq .Where and if the enum type is string it looks like that

```
.Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(someString)).
```

Now i have the option where the PropertyType is Array and i want to have this expression

```
(x => x.Any(y => y.ToLower().StartsWith(someString)));
```

But how exactly do i build such an expression?

Comment: Could you provide whole Linq expression?

Comment: While it's not too difficult to provide you with some code that calls `Any`, it would be helpful if you give us more of the context around the code you have shown here. We have no idea what `property` is for example, is it a `MemberExpression` perhaps? Or what is `f`?

Comment: you are right and I apologize for not sending the complete code piece - my bad. I updated the code.

Comment: Hint: use `nameof(string.ToLower)` instead of method name literals.

Comment: @Ian Kemp thanks for the hint will use it that way from now on.

Comment: You basically need to wrap the return from `Expression.Lambda` you have above in another `Expression.Lambda` that calls `Enumerable.Any`.

Comment: A good tool for investigating this is LINQPad. You can let the compiler build the tree for you in an `Expression<Func<>>` then use `Dump()` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. This is the code inside the case statement

```
var innerProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, PascalCase(f.PropertyName));
var innerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "y");

var toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.ToLower), new Type[] { });
var startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.StartsWith), new[] { typeof(string) });
var value = Expression.Constant(f.Value.ToLower());
var loweredProperty = Expression.Call(innerParameter, toLowerMethod);
var innerExp = Expression.Call(loweredProperty, startsWithMethod, value);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(innerExp, innerParameter);

expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(string) }, innerProperty, predicate);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing pieces of your problem but this looks like it could be solved a whole lot easier by just using a framework designed for generating expression, Dynamic Linq, OData etc